# Spark Scala join dataframe subtract column values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes each has 2 columns. I want to join them by their 1st column and subtract their 2nd columns. Here's what I have so far:

```
var x = df.select("a", "c")
          .groubBy("a")
          .count()
var y = df.select("b", "c")
          .groubBy("b")
          .count()
var z = x.join(y, x("a") === y("b"))
```

How do I perform a dataframe subtraction? Without the dataframe, I usually to mapValues{case ..=> ..}. Thanks

Comment: what do you want to substract? which columns?

Comment: i think i made a mistake, essentially i want to group by keys in "a" and "b", and sum by "c". then i want to combine the 2 dfs by key and subtract "c"s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val x = df.groubBy("a")
          .agg(sum("c").as("c1"))
          .select("a", "c1")
val y = df.groubBy("b")
          .agg(sum("c").as("c2"))
          .select("b", "c2")
val z = x.join(y, $"a" === $"b")
         .select($"a", $"c1" - $"c2")
```

Comment: for the .select in z, $"a" is interchangeable with $"b" right? it's just the key.

Comment: @ajax2000 yes. because you join a and b, they should be equal anyway